# How to get the data match with email id on real time index

Tags: sphinx

Met this below error on real time index sphinx query,

When i try to get the rows matching with email, met this error,

Anyone help me to solve this,

```
mysql ((none)) > SELECT email_id FROM email_rt;
+------------+--------+------------------+
| id         | weight | email_id         |
+------------+--------+------------------+
| 1430906348 |      1 | arnold@gmail.com |
+------------+--------+------------------+

mysql ((none)) > SELECT email_id FROM ob_enquiry_email_rt WHERE email_id='arnold@gmail.com';

ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected QUOTED_STRING, expecting CONST_INT or CONST_FLOAT or '-' near ''arnold@gmail.com''

mysql ((none)) > SELECT email_id FROM ob_enquiry_email_rt WHERE email_id="arnold@gmail.com";

ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting CONST_INT or CONST_FLOAT or '-' near '"arnold@gmail.com"'

mysql ((none)) > SELECT email_id FROM ob_enquiry_email_rt WHERE MATCH('@(email_id) arnold@gmail.com');

ERROR 1064 (42000): index ob_enquiry_email_rt: query error: no field 'gmail' found in schema

mysql ((none)) > SELECT email_id FROM ob_enquiry_email_rt WHERE MATCH('@(email_id) (arnold@gmail.com)');

ERROR 1064 (42000): index ob_enquiry_email_rt: query error: no field 'gmail' found in schema
```

Thanks in advance